# Issue: SQL Server 2012 + C#.NET number of connections keeps growing

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I have a multithreaded C# application where I need each thread to have an active connection. I can't use connection pooling unless there is a way to use static connection to update/insert multiple tables accurately in a multithreaded app without using locks.When the number of connections is around 200, it is fine.  The connection does not grow beyond this. But when I need 2200+ connections, the number of connections keep growing infinitely.

Code to create connection -

```
 @"Data Source=Server-3-PC\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****;Pooling=false";
```

I am checking connections from SSMS using -

```
sp_who2
```

Comment: Why would you need so many connections from a single application, could you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how connection pooling works. Each time a connection is re-allocated from the pool (eg. by creating a new instance of `SQLConnection`) it is *reset*. No state remains from any previous use of that connection.

Comment: I can't use connection pooling because I the inserts/updates are made in multiple threads running simultaneously.

Comment: Nope, you've still not adequately explained yourself. It still sounds like you're confused about what connection pooling does. There are sites serving thousands of users that don't generally go above using ~50 connections, because they *do* use pooling.

Comment: Ok. Let me explain in a different way. I found [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996296/c-sharp-multiple-threads-parallel-accessing-static-mysql-connection-getset) and the question here is using locks to maintain integrity. I don't want to use locking as that will slow the processing.

Comment: @TejaswiRana - that question seems to be about someone who's decided they *don't* want to use connection pooling, so they *have* to introduce locks because they're sharing a single connection object across multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Creating connections and closing within Parallel loop is not reliable. The connections should always be created outside the loop, used inside and closed outside.

Thank you all for looking into it.

To better explain this, this works -

```
 Parallel.For(0,NumSymWatching , x =>
                {
                    String conString = @"Data Source=TEJ-HP\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=DRMinutesData;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sql;Pooling=false;";
                    SqlConnection hConnectionBars = new SqlConnection(conString);
                    hConnectionBars.Open();
                    SqlCommand hCommandBars = new SqlCommand();
                    hCommandBars.Connection = hConnectionBars;

                    BuildHistoricalBarData(A[x], B[x], beginFilterTimeMinutes, hCommandBars);


                    hConnectionBars.Dispose();
                    hConnectionBars = null;

                });
```

Connections are opened, used and closed just the way you want to. However, if you create connections inside the BuildHistoricalBarData method, it will keep growing.

The reason why pooling is not used here is 'A' is an array of items that point to different tables. Even if it had been same table, hCommandBars would be changed (by threads running in parallel) and you could never perform accurate insert/update actions without using locks. Locks would then slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible for closing any connections you open.  Regardless of whether you use pooling or not, the pattern is Create a connection, open, use it for one or more SqlCommands and close it.

With respect to pooling, a connection with pooling enabled will not be re-used before it is closed, at which point the connection is reset prior to re-use.  In either method, you still need to be closing your connections.

---

With respect to multiple threads affecting use of connection pool, I don't see how that is relevant.  A SqlConnection is not thread-safe, so you should be assigning ownership of a given connection to a single thread or ensuring that only one thread accesses it at a time.  Either way, so long as you close it when you are done, you should not have issues with connection pools.

---

I understand, and I cannot say what would happen at 2k connections, but I cannot imagine the overhead of that many connections is healthy.  Given that you are going to end up limitied by either the database or the cpu, I would consider rethinking my design.  Perhaps some sort of buffering or delegation that permits fewer connections.

For example, I have an application that processes inbound EDI Files, many at a time.  Each file has around 50k records that require an update in a database.  Instead of executing 50,000 commands with one connection per file, I have a reader which produces changes that get queued for later update.

After the readers have created 5000 or so updates, the queue creates a datatable and passes it as a parameter to a stored procedure.  This allows for one roundtrip, one transaction and one connection to handle 5000 updates from many files.  We went from 200 updates per second to 17,000 updates per second.

Comment: Your last paragraph explains exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks for this. Now people asking about pooling can refer to this.

I do have Create, Use, Close pattern. It is working exactly the way (my connection count and what db shows are equal) for upto 200 connections. I have tried like 300 or 1000 after that. When I ramp up to 2200 it seems to be leaking. I am thinking maybe it is related to connection timeout because of the number of active connections? I don't know.